# Digital Ocean: Droplet to droplet communication using private networking?

Tags: networking, nginx, digital-ocean

I am working to configure Nginx as a load balancer and reverse proxy requests to a Node application on a different droplet. I have two Digital Ocean droplets (Ubuntu 18.04 for both) and have enabled private networking. My droplets are in the same region.

Am I able to use the private IP address for the `server` IP in the upstream configuration block in my nginx.conf file? My node app is running express js on port 3000.

```
upstream nodeApiApp {
  server 10.1.2.150:3000 fail_timeout=0;
  keepalive 60;
}
```

Currently, I am not able to get the two droplets to communicate. Can you provide me with hints on what the issue might be?

The web page shows this error: `504 Gateway Time-out`. While tailing the error logs for nginx, I see the following error:

```
2019/07/20 21:53:59 [error] 3136#3136: *1165 upstream timed out (110: 
Connection timed out) while connecting to upstream, client: 68.12.133.91, server: api.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/2.0", upstream: "http://10.1.2.150:3000/", host: "api.example.com"
```

When I tail my node app logs, I do not see any activity.

After SSH'ing into my load balancer droplet, I am unable to ping or telnet into my second droplet. Could it be a firewall issue? If so, what would be a common inbound/outbound rule configuration for droplet to droplet communication?

Based on the docs, I would have thought that these two virtual private server instances would have been able to communicate with each other since they are in the same region. I opted to enable the private networking when provisioning these instances. The private networking should be all setup.

Comment: How have you configured the private network on each server?

Comment: When creating a new droplet, you have the option to enable private networking which adds droplet to droplet networking within the same region. I've selected that option for both droplets. For example, my instances are both in NYC1. And the docs suggest that this should be enabled. https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/networking/private-networking/

Comment: That doesn't explain how you configured the OS!

Comment: Ok, so I don't know how to answer your question. Let's assume I didn't configure the private network on each server.

Comment: Well, typically on Ubuntu 18.04 you would do something with Netplan. If you've done nothing, then you need to actually configure your network interfaces.